# sbin: root@policykit -1/9 high CPU

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, cpu-usage

The process "sbin: root@policykit -1/9" takes high CPU in our Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS server.

Can anyone help to find what it is?

Thank You.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9H6o.png)

Answer (score 0):

I guess policykit is your server name?
More interesting is the www-data user, that is running the process: This means something website related works in the background (if you have not started another process under this user).

To help you further, you need to tell, which webserver are you running and maybe share your configuration files.

Comment: We have multiple laravel web sites running on the server. We are using Apache web server.

I guess policykit is your server name? >> No.

Comment: Ok then have a look in /usr/share/polkit-1/actions 
There should be a process, that utilizes/abuses policykit